# Calculated Column Based on Rows in Tidymodels Recipe

Tags: r, recipe, tidymodels, r-recipes

I have a dataframe as follows:

| ID | Col1 | RespID | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 729Ad | 3.2 | A |
| 2 | orange | 295gS | 6.5 | A |
| 3 | red | 729Ad | 8.4 | B |
| 4 | yellow | 592Jd | 2.9 | A |
| 5 | green | 937sa | 3.5 | B |

I would like to calculate a new column, Col5, such that its value is 1 if the row has Col4 value of A and there exists another column somewhere in the dataset a row with the same RespId but a Col4 value of B. Otherwise it’s value is 0. Then I will drop all rows with Col4 value of B, to keep just those with A. I would like to do this using the R tidymodels recipe package. I’d also like to do this all with data frames.

Here is what the desired output table would look like prior to dropping rows with Col4 value of B:

| ID | Col1 | RespID | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 729Ad | 3.2 | A | 1 |
| 2 | orange | 295gS | 6.5 | A | 0 |
| 3 | red | 729Ad | 8.4 | B | 0 |
| 4 | yellow | 592Jd | 2.9 | A | 0 |
| 5 | green | 937sa | 3.5 | B | 0 |

Comment: If this is not a statistically learned transformation from training data (like a mean or PCA) but instead something that is "constant" if you will, I think you may be better off doing such a transformation outside of recipes, before you start building your recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(RespID) %>% mutate(col5 = case_when(Col4 == 'A' & last(Col4 == 'B') ~ 1, Col4 == 'B' & first(Col4 == 'B')  ~ 0, TRUE ~ 0))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   RespID [4]
     ID Col1   RespID  Col3 Col4   col5
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 blue   729Ad    3.2 A         1
2     2 orange 295gS    6.5 A         0
3     3 red    729Ad    8.4 B         0
4     4 yellow 592Jd    2.9 A         0
5     5 green  937sa    3.5 B         0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(RespID) %>%
  mutate(Col5 = as.integer(all(c('A', 'B') %in% Col4) & Col4 == 'A')) %>%
  ungroup

#     ID Col1   RespID  Col3 Col4   Col5
#  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <int>
#1     1 blue   729Ad    3.2 A         1
#2     2 orange 295gS    6.5 A         0
#3     3 red    729Ad    8.4 B         0
#4     4 yellow 592Jd    2.9 A         0
#5     5 green  937sa    3.5 B         0
```

`all(c('A', 'B') %in% Col4)` checks that both `A` and `B` value is present in `RespID` whereas  `Col4 == 'A'` would give 1 only where `'A'` is present.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Col1 = c("blue", "orange", "red", "yellow", 
"green"), RespID = c("729Ad", "295gS", "729Ad", "592Jd", "937sa"
), Col3 = c(3.2, 6.5, 8.4, 2.9, 3.5), Col4 = c("A", "A", "B", 
"A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was wondering if there's a way to avoid using ```group_by```, but still specify the RespID within the ```mutate_ID``` clause somehow. I'm trying to integrate this into the recipes package which allows ```mutate()``` but not ```group_by```

Comment: I see. Sorry, I do not have experience working with `recipes` package.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. One other follow-up question, how would I specify this for a certain date range? I've updated my example to include a column with year, month, date. I would like to do this in groups based on say a 30 day timeframe -- so that if 'B' appears within 30 days of when 'A' appears in the dataset, only then is there a 1 present (if 'B' appears within 60 days, then there is no 1).

Comment: Please ask follow up question as a new question instead of editing the original question. It invalidates the current answers and confuses future readers @ava

Comment: Reverted this post to the original and reposted the follow-up questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69885849/calculated-column-based-on-rows-with-date-range