# Calculated Column Based on Rows with Date Range

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

| ID | Col1 | RespID | Col3 | Col4 | Year | Month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 729Ad | 3.2 | A | 2021 | April | 2 |
| 2 | orange | 295gS | 6.5 | A | 2021 | April | 1 |
| 3 | red | 729Ad | 8.4 | B | 2021 | April | 20 |
| 4 | yellow | 592Jd | 2.9 | A | 2021 | March | 12 |
| 5 | green | 937sa | 3.5 | B | 2021 | May | 13 |

I would like to calculate a new column, Col5, such that its value is 1 if the row has Col4 value of A and there exists another column somewhere in the dataset a row with the same RespId but a Col4 value of B. Otherwise it’s value is 0. Then I will drop all rows with Col4 value of B, to keep just those with A. I'd also like to account for the date fields (year, month, date) so that this is done in groups based on say a 30 day timeframe. So if 'B' appears within 30 days of when 'A' appears in the dataset, only then is there a 1 present (if 'B' appears within 60 days, then there is no 1. Additionally, I'd like to keep everything as data.frames.

Here is what the desired output table would look like prior to dropping rows with Col4 value of B:

| ID | Col1 | RespID | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 729Ad | 3.2 | A | 1 |
| 2 | orange | 295gS | 6.5 | A | 0 |
| 3 | red | 729Ad | 8.4 | B | 0 |
| 4 | yellow | 592Jd | 2.9 | A | 0 |
| 5 | green | 937sa | 3.5 | B | 0 |

I have found Ronak's solution in this thread ([Calculated Column Based on Rows in Tidymodels Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69688911/calculated-column-based-on-rows-in-tidymodels-recipe)) to be useful, however, would like to modify for the date range.

Comment: What's the point of columns `Col1` and `Col3`? Do they play a role?

Comment: Does `B` always come after `A`?

Comment: Are there always only one to two observations per `RespID`? If yes, are the `Col4` values always `A` and `A`/`B` respectively?

Comment: `Then I will drop all rows with Col4 value of B, to keep just those with A.` - Your desired output table still has row with a `Col4` value `B`. @ava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things to unpack here.
I think you're tripping up over your own feet by trying to do too many things at once. I've broken down the code into four distinct steps to make the thought process easy to follow. Obviously, for use in a production environment it should be rewritten more efficiently.

## 1. Generate some data

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)

df <- tibble(
    id = c(1:10),
    resp_id = c(1701, seq(2286, 2289), 1701, seq(2290, 2293)),
    grouping = sample(c("A", "B"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
    date = seq.Date(as.Date("2363-10-04"), as.Date("2363-11-17"), length.out = 10)
)
```

**Resulting data:**

```r
# A tibble: 10 × 4
      id resp_id grouping date      
   <int>   <dbl> <chr>    <date>    
 1     1    1701 A        2363-10-04
 2     2    2286 A        2363-10-08
 3     3    2287 A        2363-10-13
 4     4    2288 A        2363-10-18
 5     5    2289 B        2363-10-23
 6     6    1701 B        2363-10-28
 7     7    2290 B        2363-11-02
 8     8    2291 B        2363-11-07
 9     9    2292 A        2363-11-12
10    10    2293 B        2363-11-17
```

## 2. Check grouping

```r
df <- df %>%
    mutate(
        is_a = ifelse(grouping == "A", 1, 0),
        is_b = ifelse(grouping == "B", 1, 0)
    )
```

**We have the grouping now as easy-to-use dummy variables:**

```r
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 6
      id resp_id grouping date        is_a  is_b
   <int>   <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    1701 A        2363-10-04     1     0
 2     2    2286 A        2363-10-08     1     0
 3     3    2287 A        2363-10-13     1     0
 4     4    2288 A        2363-10-18     1     0
 5     5    2289 B        2363-10-23     0     1
 6     6    1701 B        2363-10-28     0     1
 7     7    2290 B        2363-11-02     0     1
 8     8    2291 B        2363-11-07     0     1
 9     9    2292 A        2363-11-12     1     0
10    10    2293 B        2363-11-17     0     1
```

## 3. Check completeness

```r
df <- df %>%
    group_by(
        resp_id
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        # Check if the grouping has both "A" and "B" values
        is_complete = ifelse(
            sum(is_a) > 0 & sum(is_b) > 0, 
            1, 
            0
        )
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
```

**We see that there is only one `resp_id` value that is complete — `1701`:**

```r
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 7
      id resp_id grouping date        is_a  is_b is_complete
   <int>   <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     1    1701 A        2363-10-04     1     0           1
 2     2    2286 A        2363-10-08     1     0           0
 3     3    2287 A        2363-10-13     1     0           0
 4     4    2288 A        2363-10-18     1     0           0
 5     5    2289 B        2363-10-23     0     1           0
 6     6    1701 B        2363-10-28     0     1           1
 7     7    2290 B        2363-11-02     0     1           0
 8     8    2291 B        2363-11-07     0     1           0
 9     9    2292 A        2363-11-12     1     0           0
10    10    2293 B        2363-11-17     0     1           0
```

## 4. Assign target value

```r
df <- df %>%
    group_by(
        resp_id
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        # Check if the "A" part of a complete grouping has a another value within 30 days
        is_within_timeframe = ifelse(
            is_complete == 1 & is_a == 1 & max(date) - min(date) <= 30, 
            1, 
            0
        )
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
```

**We see that our one complete set has in fact a `B` value that falls within 30 days of the `A` observation (*Caveat: This only works if there are always exactly one or two observations per grouping!*). Column `is_within_timeframe` corresponds to your `Col4`:**

```r
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 8
      id resp_id grouping date        is_a  is_b is_complete is_within_timeframe
   <int>   <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>               <dbl>
 1     1    1701 A        2363-10-04     1     0           1                   1
 2     2    2286 A        2363-10-08     1     0           0                   0
 3     3    2287 A        2363-10-13     1     0           0                   0
 4     4    2288 A        2363-10-18     1     0           0                   0
 5     5    2289 B        2363-10-23     0     1           0                   0
 6     6    1701 B        2363-10-28     0     1           1                   0
 7     7    2290 B        2363-11-02     0     1           0                   0
 8     8    2291 B        2363-11-07     0     1           0                   0
 9     9    2292 A        2363-11-12     1     0           0                   0
10    10    2293 B        2363-11-17     0     1           0                   0
```

Comment: @ava It seems that you’ve made a mistake copy-pasting/changing the code. Try to copy everything and running it as it is.